# Why am I unable to log-in to Apple sites with my Mac mini?

Tags: login, development

A friend just got a used Mac Mini with Snow Leopard and is having an unusual log-in issue.

The problem is that he cannot log-in to ANY Apple site with that machine. He cannot log-in to developer.apple.com, iTunes, or the Apple store. Other sites work as expected.

He can log-in to any of the Apple sites using his iPad and he also can log-in using my MacBookPro.

Any ideas on this?

The issue occurs using Chrome or Safari as the browser. It seems to be something about this machine; but I'm just not sure what files or apps or system prefs to investigate. He can log-in to Amazon and Google accounts as usual, just not Apple sites.

Comment: Is this a new OS install or are there other programs running?

Comment: The OS was installed. My friend tried re-installing OSX, but didn't seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: To clarify my question is is there only the OS or are there other programs?

Comment: Yes there are other programs. Not sure of the details since it's not my computer and it was purchased from another acquaintance.

Comment: We need to know what the other programs are e.g. Little Snitch - I suspect the easiest fix is to do an OS install erasing the disk first

Comment: What exactly happens when you log into an Apple site? What about Apple apps with network-backed features? Like logging into an account in iTunes? Or logging into iCloud/MobileMe through System Preferences?

Comment: What happens? It hangs on Apple log-in pages. Doesn't matter whether the browser is Chrome or Safari, but haven't tried Firefox.

Comment: Since you found an answer, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the computer is used the most likely cause is previous user's settings. It is worth purging all cookies as a start and, if this doesn't work, erasing the browsers entirely and reinstalling from scratch, and if this fails erase the drive and reinstall *everything* from scratch.

The only way a problem could possibly persist after this is if professional apple sites tie logins to the *hardware* ID of a specific computer.

Comment: They don't. Also, websites don't have access to hardware IDs. Not through only a web browser, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Actually fixed after switching from wireless to ethernet. And even now works wirelessly after manually assigning an IP address.

Comment: You should mark your response as answered if the problem is resolved !